# How should I manage kind of a Panel in Swing but i JAVAFX

Tags: javafx

I want to develop an application using JavaFx but I'm used to Swing, there I could create Panels and the add them to the Frame but how can I do that in JavaFx I'm confuse, beside I'm trying to use an MVC architecture so it would really help if you could give me some ideas for these; here I'm using a TabPane and each Tab has its own pane so I'd like to puts in every pane's tab a different tab which I want to design in a differente place.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use a subclass of `Pane` and set it as the content of the `Tab`. Unlike Swing, JavaFX doesn't decompose the panel and layout manager: there are just different subclasses of `Pane` that  manage their own layouts in different ways. Have you read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102)?

Comment: No, I haven't, do you have any good tutorial? I've beeen looking but what I find it's kinf od confusing, would you share it with me?

Comment: The one I linked is the official tutorial from Oracle.